# Integrate Instamojo Payment Gateway API

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, instamojo

I tried all the suggestions and tips given by Instamojo for my ASP.net 4.5(C#) application but even I face the problem on this line for 
Creating Payment Request.

```
 PaymentRequest npr = awit im.CreatePaymentRequest(pr);
```

It shows error on `CreatePaymentRequest(pr);`

Github link: https://github.com/pkbnaveen/Instamojo.NET

Comment: `awit` is a typo, you probably meant `await`. If there's an issue after using `await` as well then please include it in the question body.